# Django DateInput default set by browser

Tags: django, django-forms

In my Django project I have a regular looking forms.py which, for one form, specifies a certain field to use the DateInput widget.

This works fine - when I browse to the page, I see an empty date field on which I can click and select a date from a calendar view.

Now I'd like to auto-populate that for the user using the current date on *their* computer. So not a server-side default value, but probably browser-side set by Javascript or something.

How can I do this?

Essentially this is the template for my form:

```
<form action="/new_case/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

EDIT: Huge thanks to Håken Lid for helping with the javascript. For anyone else who comes here searching for this kind of answer, heres how one might wrap it for use in a Django form template without jQuery dependency:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
var dt = new Date();
var double_digit_day = ('0' + dt.getDate()).slice(-2);
var double_digit_month = ('0' + (dt.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
var currentDate = dt.getFullYear() + '-' + double_digit_month + '-' + double_digit_day;
document.getElementById('id_date').value = currentDate;
});
</script>
```

Where 'date' would be the name of the field in the original model on which the form is based. The id of the element on the page for a single-form is then simply 'id_date' if were the model's date field to be named 'date'.

Comment: You can use javascript to do it.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I can somehow. I am just unsure how. Django takes care of the {{ form }} expansion and so probably I'd need to write this code in the template for the form. This is essentially what I am hoping for help on - how to change the form template to include this Javascript code for the form

Comment: Check my updated answer. The `toISOString()` does not return the local date, but the UTC date. It is possible to get the correct local date is a more verbose way.

Comment: Thank you for that update - very important :)

Comment: Also `getMonth()` returns 0 indexed month... javascript is messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript to populate date inputs. Just add something like this to the page. Use a query selector that finds the correct input, in case there are several date inputs present.

```js
var dateinput = document.querySelector('input[type=date]')
var dt = new Date()
var dateString = dt.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (dt.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + dt.getDate()).slice(-2)
dateinput.value = dateinput.value || dateString
```

```html
<form>
<input type='date' />
</form>
```